# Thumbnail previews of PDF files

Tags: dired, pdf, image-dired

If I select image files in a Dired buffer and do <kbd>C-t C-t</kbd>, a nice little thumbnail appears. But if I try this with PDF files, nothing happens. I would expect to see a thumbnail of the first page of the PDF.

Is this normal? Is there an easy way to get the behavior I want? (I am running Emacs 24.3.1 on Ubuntu 14.04 if that matters.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a feature of `dired+` as far as I can tell.  `C-t C-t` is bound to `image-dired-dired-toggle-marked-thumbs`, which first checks whether the file is an image or not with `diredp-get-image-filename`.  This procedure runs `image-file-name-regexp` to generate a regular expression matching all image file names.  Then it creates thumbnails with Imagemagick's `convert` (defined in `image-dired-cmd-create-thumbnail-program`).

You should be able to modify the behaviour of `image-file-name-regexp` by adding a regular expression for PDF files to the variable `image-file-name-regexps`.  `convert` can convert PDF files to images, so you should get a thumbnail.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful info. I'm afraid this might require a defadvice then. `convert` treat PDFs differently than other images, generating a numbered image for each page in the file. Unless there is a way to modify `image-dired-cmd-create-thumbnail-program` so that it would do something like `convert file.pdf[0]`, but that may cause problems with regular images.